# reset method send nothing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a reset password method but the reset email didn’t arrive to the user mail

this is the method

```
void forgotPass()async {
    if(_emailController.text.isEmpty || !_emailController.text.contains('@')){
      Methods.ErrorDailog(subtitle: "Pleas enter a valid email", context: context);
    }else{
      setState(() {
        isLoading= true;
      });
      try {
        await authInstance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailController.text.toLowerCase());
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        Methods.ErrorDailog(subtitle: '${error.message}', context: context);
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        Methods.ErrorDailog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you check spam folder?

Comment: yes there is nothing